# Exceed capacity

Tags: java, arraylist, vector

Let's say we have simple ArrayList/Vector implementation, Here is my alloc function when we exceeded capacity

```
private void allocateCapacity(int capacity)
{
    // private Object [] m_elems;
    Object [] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(m_elems, capacity);

    Arrays.fill(m_elems, null); // this point where I confused, Should I have to write this line or not?


    m_elems = tmp;
}
```

Comment: you don't. Arrays are filled with object/primitive defaults already. And this is un-related to garbage-collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Arrays.copyOf(m_elems, capacity);
```

Will create a copy of the m_elements with size capacity. And I will reference the javadoc here:

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length.

Which means your array will already be padded with nulls if capacity is bigger than your original array.

I would have probably written a one liner:

```
m_elems = Arrays.copyOf(m_elems, capacity);
```

Comment: I am not a native english speaker, but I don't think `padded` is correct in this context, probably `filled`?

Comment: @Eugene I am not either :) But in this case I agree "filled" sounds better. But I am also non native speaker.